# Porqué los recursos *.js dentro del directorio src no se ejecutan en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

La estructura del proyecto en React lo cree mediante **create-react-app** 
Los archivos *js los guardo en el directorio **src** . He instalado **react-script-tag** para cargar los scripts.
Al ejecutar el servidor de desarrollo, aparentemente la carga de estos recursos arroja un **status code 200 OK** , pero el código javascript no se ejecuta.

**hola.js**

```
console.log("%chola", "background-color: yellow; font-size: 30px;");
```

Esta es la línea que carga un recurso *.js:

```
<Script isHydrating={false} type="text/javascript" src=  "hola.js"/>
```

Lo curioso es que mientras el recurso este dentro de **src** , no se ejecuta, pero si lo mudo al directorio **public** , se ejecuta sin problema.
Que podría hacer para evitar usar el directorio public? Porque tengo entendido que webpack no tiene en cuenta los assets dentro de **public** , por ello quiero mantener todos mis assets dentro de **src**

**Un segundo intento**
He dejado atras el **react-script-tag**  y utilizado a cambio **import**:

```
 import "./vendor/jquery/jquery.js";
  import "./vendor/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js";
  import "./vendor/bootstrap.js/bootstrap.min.js";
  import "./vendor/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js";
  import   "./vendor/waypoints/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js";
  import  "./vendor/jquery.counterup/jquery.counterup.min.js";
  import  "./vendor/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js";
  import  "./vendor/owl.carousel2.thumbs/owl.carousel2.thumbs.min.js";
  import   "./js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js";
  import   "./vendor/bootstrap-select.js/bootstrap-select.min.js";
  import   "./vendor/jquery.scrollto/jquery.scrollTo.min.js";
  import  "./js/front.js";
```

Todas estas dependencias se encuentran en sus respectivos directorios pero arroja errores en consola:

```
./src/vendor/jquery/jquery.js
Line 10324:  'define' is not defined  no-undef
Line 10325:   'define' is not defined  no-undef
```

Comment: ¿Hay alguna razón especial para no utilizar [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)?

Comment: He utilizado imports, pero me da muchos errores en la consola, por ejemplo: Line 1:  'jQuery' is not defined  no-undef , y cosas así. LO que deseo cargar son los *js de JQuery y otras cosas que necesito

Comment: Si lo instalaste con npm o yarn puedes importarlos de esta forma `import $ from 'jquery'`

Comment: El problema es que, he descargado una plantilla para un website, quise adaptarlo a react, entonces me limito a usar las librerias que la plantilla utiliza

Comment: Y si los pones en el `index.html` dentro de la carpeta `public`, funciona?